# The matplotlib callback function does not work in Visual studio Code

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python on Visual Studio Code.
I would like to create a program that when a point on a graph displayed in matplotlib is clicked, it will show that it was clicked.
To do this, I have tied the matplotlib event to a click function that I created using .canvas.mpl_connect().
However, when I run the program, it does not behave as intended and I do not get a print('clicked object').
Here is the code I ran.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def click(event):
    print('clicked object')

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', click)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The environment is as follows
・Visual Studio Code 1.60.0
・Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

As it turns out, due to my lack of research, I needed to add `picker=True` to the options of `scatter()` while plotting.

This is a rudimentary thing that can be found in the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html), but I'm leaving this question as a reminder to myself. I'll leave this question for my own reflection.

The modified code is shown below

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def click(event):
    print('clicked object')

x = np.random.randn(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', click)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.scatter(x, y, picker=True, pickradius=2.5)
plt.show()
```